# Loop through data in excel and consolodate commons fields

Tags: excel, for-loop, scripting, vba

I would like to loop through a list of company records (column a) and concatenate there sectors (column b) where there is more than one company record.

```
Raw Data    
Company Sector
Company 1   A
Company 1   B
Company 2   C
Company 2   D
Company 2   E

Desired Outcome 
Company Sector
Company 1   A, B
Company 2   C, D, E
```

Would appreciate any assistance in achieving this result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
Sub SortCompanies()
i = 2
Do
VarComp1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
VarComp2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
If VarComp1 = VarComp2 And VarComp2 <> "" Then
Set VarSec1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2)
Set VarSec2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 2)
VarSec1.Value = VarSec1.Value & "," & VarSec2.Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
i = i - 1
End If
i = i + 1
Loop While VarComp1 <> ""
End Sub
```